# Display specific fileds within map field type in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following database in firestore:
[image]

I am trying to display each fruit and then the colour in my website.
e.g.

apple red

banana yellow

orange orange

It doesn't seem to work since I have used the map data type. There are also other fields in the document that do not have colours so do not need to be found.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

here's my code:

```
var foo = []
let fruits = firestore.collection('fruit').doc('gUOqKdpvB8j0yFAJXAdH');
let getDoc = fruits.get()
  .then(doc => {
    if (!doc.exists) {
      console.log('No such document!');
    } else {
        console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
        foo = doc.data();
        console.log(foo);
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting document', err);
  });

//does not work here onwards
var colours = []
for (i=0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    if (hi[i] = "colour") {
        colours[i] = foo[i]
        console.log(colours[i] + foo[i])
    }
}
```

the code does not work. Also is there an easier way then what I have attempted above?
Do I have to read the whole document or can I  just search for the information that I need?

Comment: Can you please show the code you use in your front-end?

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to loop over the keys of the object `foo`.

```
var i = 0
var colors = []
for (var property in foo) {
  if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        colours.push(foo[property])
        console.log(property+foo[property])
    }
    i++;
  }
}
```